# Unable to resolve hostname over vpn

Tags: c#, wcf, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I've been trying get my app to connect to a WCF service within the corporate network.

We use a VPN to keep everything somewhat hidden and secure.

I've tried several different methods and I'm unable to get the phone to connect to the service.

I first added the service as a service reference, and built the client out with the correct URL, but this just did nothing and then failed with a nondescript error message after around 50sec.

I then switched to System.Net.HttpClient. This again failed after around 50sec, but this time it threw a System.Net.WebException with the message "A server with the specified hostname could not be found".

I finally tried the ModernHttpClient as well, and this had the same result as before.

(Note that I tried the first two in a test console app project on my local machine first to make sure that they would complete a request successfully)

To make sure I wasn't going crazy and that the VPN was correctly resolving the name, I created a test page within the app which solely has a WebView on it, with the source set to the service url.
I opened the app and navigated to the test page and it loaded the service definition page without a problem.

for reference, this is the current code I have using ModernHttpClient:

```
using (var client = new HttpClient(new NativeMessageHandler()))
{
    const string soap = "<soap msg>";
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("SOAPAction", "<service namespace>");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("text/xml"));

    using (var response = await client.PostAsync("http://<url>/Service.svc", new StringContent(soap, Encoding.UTF8, "text/xml")))
    {
        using (var content = response.Content)
        {
            // parse the xml result
        }
    }
}
```

Is there something special that I should be doing to tell the HttpClient that it has to use the VPN? I thought that this was handled automatically.

Comment: Is the server name internal only?  Does your VPN connection provide name resolution for the internal network?  Seems like it would work so long as name resolution and the routing table are all good.

Comment: @KrisOye the server name is internal only, yes. the vpn stuff is a bit over my head (it was setup by server engineers and security guys), but afaik the vpn (airwatch tunnel) is configured to route all traffic for apps with specific ids through to the internal network. This works from within the WebView, from Safari, and from phonegap wrapped applications - but not through the Xamarin HttpClient/ServiceReference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked into the VPN configuration to make sure it was correct.
I looked into the DNS configuration to make sure it resolves correctly.
I looked into the phone's configuration to make sure it was correct.

I eventually found the issue is a problem with Airwatch's Tunnel VPN.

The VPN only works the first time the app is launched.

If the VPN remains open and is not closed before the app is restarted, then it will not allow connections to pass through.

Expecting a patch form airwatch soon that should (hopefully) rectify the issue!